# DOMDocument on WordPress site causing UTF-8 issues

Tags: php, utf-8, domdocument

I'm building a mobile site at https://mobile.pugetsoundbasketball.com.

On the home page (https://mobile.pugetsoundbasketball.com) I'm using DOMDocument to pull content from a specific div (#upcoming_league_dates) from a page located on the main website (https://pugetsoundbasketball.com).

The main website is built in WordPress and I don't want to use WordPress on the mobile site because I only need to pull a couple WordPress pages.

```
$url = "https://pugetsoundbasketball.com/index.php";
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents($url));
$div = $doc->getElementById('upcoming_league_dates');
echo $doc->saveHTML($div);
```

This works but my problem is it's showing what I believe is UTF-8 characters like "Men€s" instead of "Men's".

I tried to change the text in WordPress to see if I can fix it that way but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell DOM what charset to use from the get-go:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');  // note the UTF-8 option.
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: Thanks, that didnt change it though :(

Comment: I updated the code to reflect your comments and show you what I currently have

Comment: As it turns out, I was missing <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> in the header file

Comment: This answer is misleading - the character set specified in the DOMDocument constructor is just overwritten when the HTML is loaded, so it does nothing. The actual answer was to make sure the encoding was specified in the output HTML.